# SQL query from php not use mysql cache

Tags: php, mysql, caching

The Mysql server is set to cache:

```
query_cache_size = 1G
query_cache_type = 1
```

When I execute the query from phpmyadmin the first time the query took 2 sec and the second time 0.0001 sec.

So the cache does work. But in the php script, the query keeps taking 2 sec every time.

```
php version 5.4.14
mysql 5.5.30
```

Script:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "search");
    $t = microtime(true);
    $res = $db-> query("SELECT 
                            i.page_id, 
                            SUM(i.weight) as w 
                        FROM
                            search.search_index i 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w1 
                            ON w1.word=i.word 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w2 
                            ON w1.word_base=w2.word_base 
                        WHERE 
                            w2.word = 'api' 
                        GROUP BY 
                            i.page_id 
                        ORDER BY NULL");
    print($res->num_rows."\n");
    print(microtime(true) - $t);
?>

<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("search");

    $t = microtime(true);
    $res = $db-> query("SELECT 
                            i.page_id, 
                            SUM(i.weight) as w 
                        FROM
                            search.search_index i 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w1 
                            ON w1.word=i.word 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w2 
                            ON w1.word_base=w2.word_base 
                        WHERE 
                            w2.word = 'api' 
                        GROUP BY 
                            i.page_id 
                        ORDER BY NULL");
    print(mysql_num_rows($res)."\n");
    print(microtime(true) - $t);
?>
```

If I try this:

```
    $t = microtime(true);
    $res = $db-> query("SELECT 
                            i.page_id, 
                            SUM(i.weight) as w 
                        FROM
                            search.search_index i 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w1 
                            ON w1.word=i.word 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w2 
                            ON w1.word_base=w2.word_base 
                        WHERE 
                            w2.word = 'api' 
                        GROUP BY 
                            i.page_id 
                        ORDER BY NULL");
    print(mysql_num_rows($res)."\n");
    print(microtime(true) - $t."\n");

    $t = microtime(true);
    $res = $db-> query("SELECT 
                            i.page_id, 
                            SUM(i.weight) as w 
                        FROM
                            search.search_index i 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w1 
                            ON w1.word=i.word 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            search.word_full w2 
                            ON w1.word_base=w2.word_base 
                        WHERE 
                            w2.word = 'api' 
                        GROUP BY 
                            i.page_id 
                        ORDER BY NULL");
    print(mysql_num_rows($res)."\n");
    print(microtime(true) - $t."\n");
?>
```

Script return

```
235899
1.8554458618164
235899
1.8542320728302
```

Mysql cache not work too.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `search_index` (
  `page_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `word` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`word`,`page_id`),
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `word_full` (
  `word` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `word_base` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`word`,`word_base`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word_base` (`word_base`,`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, if you are able to give us the table structures including keys then it will help.  It is most likely that your column types or keys are not suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpmyadmin modify query

```
SELECT 
    i.page_id, 
    SUM(i.weight) as w 
FROM
    search.search_index i 
INNER JOIN 
    search.word_full w1 
    ON w1.word=i.word 
INNER JOIN 
    search.word_full w2 
    ON w1.word_base=w2.word_base 
WHERE 
    w2.word = 'api' 
GROUP BY 
    i.page_id 
ORDER BY NULL
```

To

```
SELECT 
    i.page_id, 
    SUM(i.weight) as w 
FROM
    search.search_index i 
INNER JOIN 
    search.word_full w1 
    ON w1.word=i.word 
INNER JOIN 
    search.word_full w2 
    ON w1.word_base=w2.word_base 
WHERE 
    w2.word = 'api' 
GROUP BY 
    i.page_id 
ORDER BY NULL
LIMIT 0, 30
```

add **LIMIT 0,30** то the end of query.

And size of query > query_cache_limit

I increased query_cache_limit to 10M.

Answer (score 2):

Every call in PHP is a new instance, which is not relevant from the previous one. Unless you explicitly declare it.

Take a look at query caching: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php

Comment: I assume he is potentially referring to the mysql internal query caching potentially

Comment: I test mysqlnd-qc yesterday. Not working too. And phpmyadmin not work thich mysqlnd

Comment: Used the constant in the query aswell?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that `word_full.word_base` and `word_full.word` are both VARCHAR columns.  If this is not the case please provide full table structure including keys for both search_index and word_full tables.

I would

1. add a wordID column to word_full (INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL) and make that the Primary KEy
2. add a UNIQUE key on word_full.word
3. change word_base to reference wordID (so now wordID and word_base are both numeric)
4. add a key to word_full.word_base
5. change search_index.word to be search_index.wordID
6. add a key to search_index.wordID

Changing words to run off a numeric key will allow MySQL to use the indexes far more efficiently.  At present (I assume) you are joining a varchar column twice, and then searching a varchar column.  This is quite inefficient.

Lastly, moving the WHERE into the JOIN would potentially allow it to reduce the rows at a different point and so potentally be more optimal.  This gives a final query of

```
SELECT 
    i.page_id, 
    SUM(i.weight) as w 

FROM search.search_index i 

INNER JOIN search.word_full w1 
    ON w1.wordID = i.wordID

INNER JOIN search.word_full w2 
    ON w1.wordID_base = w2.wordID_base 
    AND w2.word = 'api' 

GROUP BY i.page_id 
ORDER BY NULL
```

Comment: Query work good. Mysql used if I use phpmyadmin and mysql from console.